# Solving coupled differential equations with 4 unknown constants

Tags: differential-equations

Recently I just started *Mathematica* for solving differential equations. Then I tried following 7 coupled differential equations with four unknown constants $ (a, b, c, d) $. But after completion of the `DSolve`, there was no output in it.

```
eqns = {

250*p'[t] == 10*(y[t] - p[t]),

0.15*x'[t] == 10*(p[t] - x[t]),

75*y'[t] == 10*(x[t] - y[t]) + b*z[t] - a*y[t],

2.6*z'[t] == a*y[t] - b*z[t] - c*z[t] + d*k[t], 

1.3*k'[t] == c*z[t] - d*k[t] + 3*(m[t] - k[t]),

0.15*l'[t] == 3*(k[t] - l[t]),

250*m'[t] == 3*(l[t] - m[t]),

p[0] == 5, x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, z[0] == 0, k[0] == 0, l[0] == 0, m[0] == 0};

soln = DSolve[eqns, {p, x, y, z, k, l, m}, t] [[1]] // FullSimplify
```

Actually I referred some similar Q&A here but unfortunately it couldn't work. 
So I really appreciate it if you can help me with my problem.

Comment: It is almost hopeless to get analytical solutions. So you can consider using numeric methods, such as `NDSolve` and `NDSolveValue`, before which, however, you should specify $ (a, b, c, d) $ explicitly.

Comment: You can solve your problem analytically  using `MatrixExp`. But you will get a huge expression.